# Using STM32 Timer->GPIO transfer to handle WS2812B LED timing data

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, stm32

I've been working on a lighting controller, but haven't had any luck in transferring data through GPIO. I'm using the STM32F303VCT6, and HAL library. I used the [WS2812B Library](https://github.com/hubmartin/WS2812B_STM32F3/) for STM32F3 by Hubmartin as reference, modifying it to handling LED timing data transfer in a single DMA transfer as opposed to bitbanding timing data into a two LED length buffer through circular DMA.

My plan has been to use DMA to start every GPIO that's set to LED output, to output 'high' on timer update event. Then on event CC1 to write given pins to 'low' through buffer data. And then on event CC2 to set all pins 'low'. This should allow me to handle the timing data for multiple strips in parallel. Here is my implementation:

To initialize timer:

```
static void TIM2_init(void){
    __HAL_RCC_TIM2_CLK_ENABLE();

    tim_period =  SystemCoreClock / 800000;
    uint32_t cc1 = (10 * tim_period) / 36;
    uint32_t cc2 = (10 * tim_period) / 15;

    Tim2Handle.Instance = TIM2;
    Tim2Handle.Init.Period            = tim_period;
    Tim2Handle.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
    Tim2Handle.Init.Prescaler         = 0;
    Tim2Handle.Init.ClockDivision     = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    Tim2Handle.Init.CounterMode       = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&Tim2Handle);

    tim2OC1.OCMode       = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
    tim2OC1.OCPolarity   = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
    tim2OC1.Pulse        = cc1;
    tim2OC1.OCFastMode   = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
    HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&Tim2Handle, &tim2OC1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

    tim2OC2.Pulse        = cc2;
    HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&Tim2Handle, &tim2OC2, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
}
```

To initialize DMA:

```
static void DMA_init(void){
    __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

    dmaUpdate.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    dmaUpdate.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    dmaUpdate.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_DISABLE;
    dmaUpdate.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_WORD;
    dmaUpdate.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_WORD;
    dmaUpdate.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    dmaUpdate.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;
    dmaUpdate.Instance = DMA1_Channel2;
    HAL_DMA_Init(&dmaUpdate);
    __HAL_LINKDMA(&Tim2Handle, hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_UPDATE], dmaUpdate);

    dmaCC1.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    dmaCC1.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    dmaCC1.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    dmaCC1.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_WORD;
    dmaCC1.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_HALFWORD;
    dmaCC1.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    dmaCC1.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;
    dmaCC1.Instance = DMA1_Channel5;
    HAL_DMA_Init(&dmaCC1);
    __HAL_LINKDMA(&Tim2Handle, hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC1], dmaCC1);

    dmaCC2.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    dmaCC2.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    dmaCC2.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_DISABLE;
    dmaCC2.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_WORD;
    dmaCC2.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_WORD;
    dmaCC2.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    dmaCC2.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;
    dmaCC2.Instance = DMA1_Channel7;
    HAL_DMA_Init(&dmaCC2);
    __HAL_LINKDMA(&Tim2Handle, hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC2], dmaCC2);

    dmaCC2.XferCpltCallback  = DMA_TransferCompleteHandler;
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel7_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel7_IRQn);
}
```

To begin a transfer:

```
static void WS2812_sendbuf(){
    ws2812b.transferComplete = 0;

    HAL_DMA_Start(&dmaUpdate,(uint32_t)WS2812_IO_High, (uint32_t)&WS2812B_PORT->BSRR, BUFFER_SIZE);
    HAL_DMA_Start(&dmaCC1,(uint32_t)ws2812bDmaBitBuffer, (uint32_t)&WS2812B_PORT->BRR, BUFFER_SIZE);
    HAL_DMA_Start_IT(&dmaCC2,(uint32_t)WS2812_IO_Low, (uint32_t)&WS2812B_PORT->BSRR, BUFFER_SIZE);
    __HAL_TIM_ENABLE_DMA(&Tim2Handle, TIM_DMA_UPDATE);
    __HAL_TIM_ENABLE_DMA(&Tim2Handle, TIM_DMA_CC1);
    __HAL_TIM_ENABLE_DMA(&Tim2Handle, TIM_DMA_CC2);

    __HAL_TIM_ENABLE(&Tim2Handle);
}
```

To callback on completion of DMA output:

```
void DMA1_Channel7_IRQHandler(void){
    HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&dmaCC2);
}

void DMA_TransferCompleteHandler(DMA_HandleTypeDef *DmaHandle){
    WS2812B_PORT->BSRR = WS2812_IO_Low[0];

    __HAL_TIM_DISABLE_DMA(&Tim2Handle, TIM_DMA_UPDATE);
    __HAL_TIM_DISABLE_DMA(&Tim2Handle, TIM_DMA_CC1);
    __HAL_TIM_DISABLE_DMA(&Tim2Handle, TIM_DMA_CC2);
    __HAL_TIM_DISABLE(&Tim2Handle);

    ws2812b.transferComplete = 1;
}
```

Although I can verify that the initial implementation works as intended, there's some glitchy behavior in the current HAL driver, which I am attempting to overcome through having all my data available before the timing data transmission begins.

In my current implementation, I send a single data buffer and begin the timing data transmission, and then delay 100 milliseconds before starting the process again. I am confused to find that my implementation doesn't appear to send out any data at all through GPIO, and I assume that I've made mistakes in my state logic / timer start. Does anyone see a mistake that I've made to cause no output?

Comment: tim2OC2 is not fully initialized.

Comment: How/when do you start timer 2?

Comment: I love HAL 100000 lines of completely insane code to archive this (it is from my working code - I sold about 20000 devices - no complains) https://ideone.com/Vstpgj